# Preciso de ajuda no Docker

Tags: docker

Olá, eu criei meu Dockerfile e adicionei algumas funções, porém eu preciso executar um comando dentro dele e não consigo.

CMD java -Xmx$SERVER_RAM -Xms$SERVER_RAM -jar $SERVER_JAR nogui (ele inicia e aparece as logs no `docker logs -f`) porém, quando eu tento executar um comando com o docker exec ele executa no sistema e não no aplicativo, eu tentei pelo docker attach e ele abre a log do servidor para digitar, eu tentei usar `echo "op" | docker attach <container_id>` e ele não executa. Alguém sabe como executar?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro sua pergunta está muito vaga, e precisa de novas informações sobre, qual é a imagem que está utilizando para criar o `container`, se trata de uma aplicação, um OS `linux`(qual disto) e se ela se trata de uma versão [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine) (da qual é o mais clean possível, se for o caso, pode em muitas vezes não possuir um attach).

Outra solução é criar um `container` utilizando o comando `docker exec -it nomeOS <container-ID-or-name> bash`.

Outra opção, é seguir o exemplo dessa pergunta do [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573698/why-does-docker-attach-hang) em inglês da qual é bem semelhante ao problema do attach.